# Advertencia en consulta php mysql: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

```html
$sql_ss = "SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_ES'; SELECT DAYNAME(fecha_inscripcion) DIA,COUNT(fecha_inscripcion) REGISTROS FROM persona WHERE WEEK(fecha_inscripcion)= WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY fecha_inscripcion,DAYNAME(fecha_inscripcion) ORDER BY fecha_inscripcion;";
$resultss = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_ss);


while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($resultss))
  {      
    echo 'Dia: '.$rowss[0];
    echo ' Registros: '.$rowss[1].'<br><br>';
  }
              
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\ejemplo.php on line 80
```

El código funciona perfectamente si le quito el SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_ES'; a la consulta. Me comentaron en otro foro que el error es porque estoy ejecutando dos query en la mista consulta, pero ¿cómo lo soluciono? Necesito devolver los días de la semana en español.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La consulta debe ser así: `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';` Además de eso, si no recuerdo mal, la función `query` no permite múltiples consultas, tendrías que usar `multi_query`, pero no interesa para este caso, porque luego parece que necesitas usar los resultados de la segunta consulta. Por tanto, lo propio sería mandar dos consultas aparte, primero `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';`  y luego la segunda consulta.

Comment: mysqli_query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';");

Puse eso antes q la consulta. y ahora me arroja este error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\ejemplo.php on line 77

Comment: Siempre que uses `mysqli_query` tienes que pasarle en primer parámetro la conexión. Intenta así: `mysqli_query($conexion,"SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';");` y para la segunda consulta también tienes que pasarle la conexión.

Comment: Tenias razón. (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a ejecutar primero.

```
  $sql = "SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_ES';";
   mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Luego ejecutas la siguiente consulta.